# Why does overriding the Text property of a textbox make Visual Studio crash?

Tags: c#, textbox, overriding

I tried to create a new control out of a `TextBox` called `RialiTextBox` which is a kind of currency textbox.

The problem is that when I override the `Text` property, and then build the control, upon dragging the newly created TextBox on the form, Visual Studio crashes.

I even tried the `new` keyword, but then again I got a "stack overflow error". What am I doing wrong?

Here is the snippet of code I'm talking about:

```
public override string Text
{
    get
    {
        if (this.Text.Contains(" ريال")) {
            return this.Text.Replace(" ريال", "");
        }
        return base.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        base.Text = value;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

I followed the suggested solution in which wanted me to change all `this.Text` to `base.Text`. Doing this solved the Visual Studio crashing and the "stack over flow error message", but I also noticed my overridden onEnter event stopped functioning too!

When I completely commented out the overridden Text property of my new control, the event went functional again! What is causing this?

```
protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Mode == Modes.ریالی)
        {
            if (this.Text.Contains(" ريال"))
            {
                this.Text = this.Text.Replace(" ريال", "");
            }
        }
        base.OnEnter(e);
    }
```

Comment: You have an infinite loop. Your `Text` getter is getting itself. I think you meant to use `base` in a few places instead of `this`.

Comment: @vcsjones that sounds like an answer, rather than a comment

Comment: @MikhailKozhevnikov Fair enough, answer it is then.

Answer (score 3):

You have an infinite loop. Your Text getter is getting itself. I think you meant to use `base` in a few places instead of `this`.

```
    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            if (base.Text.Contains(" ريال"))
            {
                return base.Text.Replace(" ريال", "");
            }
            return base.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Text = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In these lines

```
            if (this.Text.Contains(" ريال")) 
            { 
                return this.Text.Replace(" ريال", ""); 
            }
```

you request, to your overridden control, to return its text to be replaced in case it contains the searched string. But this triggers again the GET accessor in an infinite loop. Ending with the stackoverflow exception

Change to

```
            if (base.Text.Contains(" ريال")) 
            { 
                return base.Text.Replace(" ريال", ""); 
            }
```

Comment: my overridden onEnter event stopped functioning after i used this method!

Comment: Could you update your question with the code in your OnEnter?

Comment: i added the OnEnter event to the first post :)

Comment: Have you tried to replace also in this method the call to this.Text with base.Text?

Comment: the return value is fine , i mean the text is striped form "ریال" in case it contains it , but the textbox itself doesnt get updated ! and still shows the ریـال  sign allways . 
both this and base has this problem .

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an endless recursion

```
this.Text
```

calls the getter, i.e., the getter calls itself in an endless loop!

Change `this.Text` to `base.Text`. The `if` test is not necessary. If the pattern is not contained, the `Replace` method will return the original text anyway.

```
public override string Text
{
    get { return base.Text.Replace(" ريال", ""); }
    set { base.Text = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a local variable to use in your Text property.
The problem is you have recursive calls to `Text` property `this.Text` , use `base.Text` instead.

Example:

```
public override string Text
        {
            get
            {
                string text = base.Text;
                if (text.Contains(" ريال"))
                {
                    return text.Replace(" ريال", "");
                }
                return base.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                base.Text = value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This would work in other situations, however here, the OP wants to change the behavior of the TextBox, and since the text entered in the TextBox and the text displayed by the TextBox are represented by the `Text` property, this one must be used!